# Issue with split() using maxsplit

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Very basic issue I'm sure, I'm trying to set a !status command to change my bot's status. The following code works:

```py
@myBot.event        
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('!status'):
   m = message.content.split(' ')
   await myBot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=m[1]))
```

So nothing really complicated here, it will set the bot's status to whatever I type after `!status`.

However, it will stop after the first space, because I take `m[1]` without a `maxsplit`. Now, if I add `maxsplit=1` to my `split()` function, I can get everything after the first space in `m[1]`. This seems perfect, right? Let's say I just input the same thing as before, something like `!status test`, surprise, it doesn't work, the status doesn't update even though `m[1]` only contains `test`. Why? What does `maxsplit=1` really change that I can't see with a `print(m[1])`?

Comment: The trailing spaces/newlines?

Comment: @user1620443 could you elaborate? I tried writing the actual output to a file and there isn't any space at the end of `m[1]` nor any linebreak. At least none that I could see in a textfile...

Comment: `m = message.content[7:].strip()` since you already know the message starts with `!status`

Comment: Could you add a [mcve]? Something that doesn't need an `await` and complex checks (i.e. `message.author.server_permissions.manage_messages`). Simply demonstrate your issue with a simple string and `split` - that would be perfect.

Comment: Was just my two cents on what could be not visible from a call to print, but may make a difference on the behavior of the function. There is not enough code to be sure.

Comment: @user1620443 well I don't have "more code", unless you mean the `import discord` and the logging part.

Comment: @MSeifert how could this be more simple exactly, it's 5 lines of code? I will remove the optional `if` but it's still the same code.

Comment: @MSeifert removed the kinda useless if. It's minimal and complete. To be verifiable you have to import the discord API and create an actual bot, which would be quite complicated overall. The fact is there must be some difference in m[1] when I type `!status test` whether I use `maxsplit=1` or nothing like in my code above. I don't know how to make this code works without the await, sorry.

Comment: @dnLL We can't reproduce your problem, as your code can't be executed without the whole bot thing. A minimal example would be something like `content = 'the message as you really got it'`, so that we can immediately compare the ouput of `split` with or without maxsplit

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes but it's invisible and only doesn't work as a discord.change_presence() parameter...

Comment: @dnLL a string ss of two words without trailing spaces will give the same output if you call ss.split() and ss.split(maxsplit=1). So, either there are trailing spaces, or there are mysterious evil forces working against you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `maxplit` you don't have everything after the first whitespace, then `m[1]` *just* contains everything between the first and second whitespace (if present).

With just one whitespace they are identical:

```
>>> str1 = '!status test'
>>> str1.split()
['!status', 'test']

>>> str1.split(maxsplit=1)
['!status', 'test']
```

But with more than one they aren't:

```
>>> str2 = '!status test debug'
>>> str2.split()            # 3 elements
['!status', 'test', 'debug']

>>> str2.split(maxsplit=1)  # 2 elements
['!status', 'test debug']
```

I think what you really want is to strip away the `!status`:

```
>>> str1[len('!status '):]  # or hardcode the length: `[8:]`
'test'

>>> str2[len('!status '):]
'test debug'
```

Or even easier [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> str1 = '!status test'
>>> str2 = '!status test debug'
>>> str1.partition(' ')
('!status', ' ', 'test')
>>> str2.partition(' ')
('!status', ' ', 'test debug')
```

There the third element always contains everything after the first whitespace. You could even check if the first element `== '!status'`

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly using `split(maxsplit=1)` or `split(' ')`, but won't work using `split(' ',maxsplit=1)` even though m[1] seems to return the same string when using `!status test` as an input. Thoughts on that? My initial problem is solved though.

Comment: I'm probably gonna delete considering all the downvotes and close requests I'm receiving. I still think it's interesting.

Comment: Could you show the `repr(message.content)` and `type(message.content)`? I think it will also make the question clearer and maybe some of the downvoters will reverse the downvote.

Comment: If I do print(repr(message.content)), I get `'!status test'`. I'm using the latest version of Python (AFAIK). Problem is only when I add the `' '` parameter (which is mandatory when it's a space from what I read but I also read the behavior is kinda different).

Comment: Yes, with `' '` it only splits at `' '`, while without the `' '` it splits at every whitespace (including tabs, linebreaks, etc.). However your given string seems like it *should* work either way.

Comment: The split still happens either way. Very weird, I'd like to think it has to do with the Discord.py API but if it's the same string, it shouldn't matter. Anyway, it works without the `' '` so I marked your answer as accepted since you did the best efforts to help me. Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way would be to check `print(message.content.split(' ')[1] == message.content.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[1])` or compare their `len`gths. If that prints `False` it will be because there are some whitespaces after the first one.